# Rendering a component on SelectOneMenu value - JSF PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

With PrimeFaces I'd like to render a second component if the selected value on a SelectOneMenu is equal to a given value.
Possibly without sending the value of the SelecOneMenu to the server to avoid useless traffic.
What do I do wrong here? I suppse should be something similar...

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{helpRequest.helpKind}" id="selectList">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="One Time" itemValue="1" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Recurrent" itemValue="2" />
     <p:ajax update="dependingComponent"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>                        


<h:panelGroup id="dependingComponent" rendered="selectlist.value== 2" >
     <p:outputLabel>Label: </p:outputLabel>
     <p:calendar value="#{calendarView.date1}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You may need to enclose the `<h:panelGroup>` in a different container possibly another `<h:panelGroup>` and update the outer most `<h:panelGroup>` instead. So that the inner `<h:panelGroup>` can be rendered depending upon the model value set by a `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: That was the solution. :)